# Using Excel and Sorting Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a spreadsheet with over 1500 rows and 20 columns, in column C I have manufacturer as my header and below it 1500 listed names, one for each row.  How do I extract the names into a single listing of just the 60-70 specific vendors, is there an easy way to set this up so that I can update my listing as I add another 500-1000 rows of data to my spreadsheet over the next few weeks?

Comment: It is unclear what you want.  Do you want a list of each unique manufacturer, or do you want to create a filter that only shows those lines from a select group of manufacturers?

Comment: I want to list each unique manufacturer.

Comment: But I would like to see this list update regularly as we build from 1500 rows to 3000 rows over the next few weeks.  I know I have 170 unique manufacturers today, I just want to build a solid process for tracking over time.  Thanks.

Comment: Then the best bet would be vba.

Comment: I've never used it, so I guess start with that learning process first, you would suggest a ground up approach?

Comment: If it something you will do only sporadically you could simply copy the entire column to another page then use DATA-->Remove Duplicates.  It will give you only the unique values.

Comment: You are a rock star, thanks Scott...have a great day

Answer (score 1):

Assume that column **C** holds the data with some duplicated records and we want the unique list *(list without duplicates)* in column **Z**.  Enter the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim C As Range, Z As Range

    Set C = Range("C:C")
    Set Z = Range("Z:Z")
    If Intersect(Target, C) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Z.Clear
        C.Copy Z
        Z.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

whenever changes are made to column **C**, the list in column **Z** will be re-created.  Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use pivot tables. Then you can do this sort of thing (and much much more) in your sleep!

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Drag the vendor column to the row labels and it will automatically condense the list into the distinct values for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all your data in manufacturer column.
2. Go to Data > Data Tools section > Remove duplicates.

It will delete your duplicated data. You will get unique manufacturers.
I recommend to work on a clean spreadsheet. Copy only manufacturer column and work.